# How to determine the Absorption coefficient of the material shown as follow? paper plus + air?

Tags: acoustics

Acoustic absorption refers to the process by which a material, structure, or object takes in sound energy when sound waves are encountered, as opposed to reflecting the energy.

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(acoustics)) gives a table for Absorption coefficients of common materials

How to determine the Absorption coefficient of the material shown as follow? paper plus + air?

[image]

Comment: What equipment do you have available?

Answer (score 1):

**Absorption coefficients are empirically determined.**

I had a very interesting visit to an acoustics lab many years ago, and got to see this very thing in person. Often the work is conducted in a [*reverberation room*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverberation_room):

[image: reverb room]

The goal is to approximate a diffuse, random-incidence sound field. A speaker plays a known sound in the room. The rectangular panel in the image can be replaced with a test panel (like your cardboard.)

I won't quote the classic work on the subject ([Christler and Snyder 1930](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/5/jresv5n4p957_A2b.pdf)) too extensively - you should have a look yourself. The basic idea is that you have two difference absorption coefficients $a_1$ (the room), and $a_2$ (the panel) representing different surface areas $S_1$ (the room without the panel) and $S_2$ (the panel). The sound source's intensity in the room ($A_1$) doesn't change.

The authors write that this reduces the acoustic intensity of the of the room from:

> $\frac{4 A_1}{a_1 Sv}$ to $\frac{4 A_1}{(a_1 S_1 + a_2 S_2)v}$

Note that the latter *must* be smaller, because $a_2$ is larger. 

They then relate intensity to decay time, allowing $a_2$ to be solved:

> $a_1 S_1 + a_2 S_2 = \frac{4V \ 2.3 \ log_{10}(\frac{E_1}{E_2})}{v(t^{1}_{2} -t^{'}_{1})}$

As you can see this requires quite a few known values: the surface area of the room ($S$), it's volume ($V$), the measured intensity in the room in both scenarios ($E_1, E_2$), and the decay times ($t^{'}_1, t^{1}_{2}$). In other words, it's not a trivial task to determine absorption coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do you put the panel, the whole wall or part of the wall?

Comment: @zghqh Presumably, the rectangular outline on the wall (to the left of the door in the picture) marks the place where you put it. Looks like there are four metal clamps attached to the wall near the four corners, probably to hold the panel in place. I'd bet that the bulbous looking thing way up in the upper-left corner is a loudspeaker. (Its shape somewhat resembles a loudspeaker that I have seen hanging over the center of a gymnasium.)

Comment: I don't know what the object in the upper-left corner is, to be honest, but yes - the four metal clamps mark the area where the panel would go.

Comment: Although this room could be used as a "reverberation chamber" to be honest it seems quite small for that purpose (the modal behaviour can extend quite high in the frequency range of interest), but can't say for sure, since we can't see the whole room. In most (not all though) cases the specimens are placed on the floor. It is easier to place and you can usually accommodate larger samples. For more info, you can check ISO 354:2003 (reverberation room measurements) as well as ISO 10534-1:1996 and ISO 10534-2:1998 (impedance tube measurements).

Comment: I came across a paper today which may be of some help here. Haven't read through but maybe it has something "useful" in there. It's the [Measurement of the sound-absorption coefficient in situ: The reflection method using periodic pseudo-random sequences of maximum length](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003682X93900322) by Massimo Garai.